# Directories are not being created on live node server but working fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a an express API that creates a folder for every order being placed in public>uploads>orders folder. The order directory has further sub directories and images inside those. Its working fine on localhost but when i deployed the API on heroku, order directory isnt being created as the server gives the "File not Found" exception as shown in the attached screenshot.

Heres the code inside the method that creates the order folder.

```
  // create order folder
  if (Order.hasPhotos(products)) {
    fs.mkdir(`public/uploads/orders/Order-${orderTransactionId}`, () => {
      console.log("Order Directory Created");
    });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    // create product folder
    if (products[i].photos.length > 0) {
      fs.mkdir(`public/uploads/orders/Order-${orderTransactionId}/Product-${i + 1}`, () => {
        console.log("PRoduct Directory Created");
      });
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < products[i].photos.length; j++) {
      fsExtra.move(`public/uploads/orders/temporary/${Order.getfilename(products[i].photos[j])}`, `public/uploads/orders/${products[i].photos[j]}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          success = false;
          throw err;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add actual error message there is probably a clue there.

Comment: @kevintechie 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iTLt.jpg

heres the error's screenshot

Comment: If these are important files you'll have to store them somewhere off the local filesystem. Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral; any changes you make to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. That happens at least once per day. Amazon S3 is a common choice.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much for your response. And my apologies for the screenshot. What about hostinger's VPS (Virtual Private Server). If i use that my files wont be lost right? Because the files arent very confidential and I just need to store these files for max 4 to 5 days.

Comment: if i want to switch to a cloud service i will have to change the code alot. Because i am creating folders with sub folders and files in them. And the admin downloads the zip of those folders and he needs the directory structure as it is.

Comment: I don't know that provider, but "VPS" generally means "it's your server to do whatever you want with". It'd probably work.